# Check state of value with case statement after pressing a button

Tags: swift, switch-statement

```
    @IBAction func sortList(_ sender: Any) {
    var stateOfList = 0
    var sortedList = array
    switch stateOfList {
    case 0:
        sortedList = array.sorted { ($0.priceUsd!) > ($1.priceUsd!) }
        stateOfList = 1
    case 1:
        sortedList = array.sorted { ($0.priceUsd!) < ($1.priceUsd!) }
        stateOfList = 2
    case 2:
        sortedList = array.sorted { ($0.rank) < ($1.rank) }
        stateOfList = 0
    default:
        stateOfList = 0
    }


    array = sortedList
    tableView.reloadData()
    print(stateOfList)
}
```

I want to sort a array and change the state of the list after pressing a button. The second press should sort the array in the other direction. But the compiler tells me "Will never be executed". What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

make **var stateOfList** an instance property of the view controller to save the state and access it again in the second press.

```
var stateOfList = 0
```

Your function will be like

```
@IBAction func sortList(_ sender: Any) {
    var sortedList = array
    switch stateOfList {
    case 0:
        sortedList = array.sorted { ($0.priceUsd!) > ($1.priceUsd!) }
        stateOfList = 1
    case 1:
        sortedList = array.sorted { ($0.priceUsd!) < ($1.priceUsd!) }
        stateOfList = 2
    case 2:
        sortedList = array.sorted { ($0.rank) < ($1.rank) }
        stateOfList = 0
    default:
        stateOfList = 0
    }

    array = sortedList
    tableView.reloadData()
    print(stateOfList)
}
```

Comment: You mean to make stateOfList an instance property of the view controller

Answer (score 0):

var stateOfList is just a local variable in that function. It is initialised to 0, each time the function is called, so only case 0 will ever be executed.

You need to make stateOfList an instance variable.